# How to add fields to a content type?

Tags: 8, installation

I installed Drupal 8 minimum. 
Create content type. Like normal there is one field. The body field.

I can't add an other field. In extend/modules all field types are enabled. Also fields and fields UI. What am I missing or have to enable to add fields to content type like: Image, link, references, etc.

I ran `drush cr` a couple of times.

Answer (score 4):

I highly suggest that you do not use the **minimal** install in Drupal, and go with the **standard** install.

It is way more efficient to use the standard install and then remove the modules that you do not want, than to use the minimal install and install a bunch of stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with using Standard.

That said, you're probably just missing the local actions block, you probably also can't see an "Add content" button on /admin/content. Go to block layout and make sure all the standard blocks like Page title, local actions, local tasks, messages and so on are there.